# int array to opengl texture in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera

I'm trying to add some efects to the camera in android,
I found some things on internet but I got stuck when creating the texture,

I use the funcion decodeYUV420SP() that returns me a int[width*height] RGB array with the hex values into each array position,

Now, I want to create an openGL texture of this array but i dont know how, I can convert each hex value to its R_G_B separated and put it into opengl but it doesn't work
I do something like this:

```
mNewTexture = new int[width*height*4]
    for(int i=0; i<mRGB.length; i=i+4){

        mNewTexture[i]   = getR(mRGB[i])   ;            //R
        mNewTexture[i+1] = getG(mRGB[i])   ;            //G
        mNewTexture[i+2] = getB(mRGB[i])   ;            //B
        mNewTexture[i+3] = getA(mRGB[i]);       //A

    }
```

To convert the hex value to RGBA (from 0 to 255)

And i do this to convert it to the openGL texture:

```
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, 1024, 512, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_FLOAT, FloatBuffer.wrap(mNewTexture));
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
```

However something is worng, cause it doesn't work...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you try to wrap your int array as a FloatBuffer? Most of your conversions are unnecessary.

Just take your original texture, wrap it in a bytebuffer, and pass it to glTexImage with the type GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE. There's no need to create a new array from what you already have.

`gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, 1024, 512, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ByteBuffer.wrap(mRGB));`